# construct HTML with AJAX interrupt via Flask

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax

So I am using an existing code "Vertical time-line" from [here](https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/), and now I am trying to make it robust. each news feed on timeline has a small code snipt of;

```
   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
        <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-movie">
            <img src="static/img/cd-icon-movie.svg" alt="Movie">
        </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

        <div class="cd-timeline-content">
            <h2>Title of section 2</h2>
            <p>Hello this is a Feed 1</p>
            <button class="cd-read-more" id="btn">Read more</button>
            <span class="cd-date">Jan 18</span>
        </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
    </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->
```

and below this I am writing a span with id="new_feeds", like;

```
<span id="new_feeds"></span>
```

just for the sake of testing, I am creating a simple AJAX call when the button from above news feed is pressed;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btn").click(function(){
       $.post('btn_clicked', function(data, status){
         $("#new_feeds").text(data);
       });
       return false;
      });
   })
```

The data that is returned back from AJAX call is handled in my Flask application:

```
@app.route("/btn_clicked", methods=['POST'])
def btn():
   print'got btn' 
   new_feeds = ''' <div class="cd-timeline-block">
        <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-movie">
            <img src="static/img/cd-icon-movie.svg" alt="Movie">
        </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

        <div class="cd-timeline-content">
            <h2>Title of section 2</h2>
            <p>Hello this is a new Feed </p>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
            <span class="cd-date">Jan 18</span>
         </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
       </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->  '''
   return new_feeds
```

All I get back in my browser is text formed HTML code like this;

[image]

Am I missing something over here ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to `from flask import Markup` and `return Markup(new_feeds)` instead of `return new_feeds`?

Comment: @Phillip Nopes ...Let me try that

Comment: Nopes, that didn't worked. Daniel got the point where I was doing the mistake. Thank you for your input @Phillips :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert the new content as html, not text.

```
   $.post('btn_clicked', function(data, status){
     $("#new_feeds").html(data);
   })
```

Comment: such a little mistake, Thankyou @Daniel (y), that worked like a charm. Now the issue is, I need to get rid of this span thingi, cuz I want that every time I press a button, a new feed on timeline should pop-up, but this updates the existing span items:/... Any suggestion for that ?